# C++ GPA Calc: How to loop one section of code a specific number of times depending on user input

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Complete c++ beginner so I'm sorry for the weird looking code.
For this part of my code:

```
cout << "Enter number of courses: \t";
cin >> numbCourses;
```

How do I make a loop so if the user enters that they have more than 1 course the user will be asked all the GPA/class questions again?
For example if a user enters that they have 3 courses, I would like the code to do three loops only with this portion of my code:

```
//input data
cout << "Enter number of courses: \t";
cin >> numbCourses;
cout << "Enter course name: \t";
cin >> courseName;
cout << "Enter the Credit Hours: \t";
cin >> creditHours;
cout << "Enter Grade Earned (as A = 4 | B = 3 | C = 2 | D = 1): \t";
cin >> grade;
cout << endl;
```

I was thinking of doing a while loop like for example:

```
while (numbcourses >=2)
```

but I know that's incorrect. Below I pasted the rest of my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


//Needed variables

int numbCourses = 0, creditHours = 0, grade = 0, totalCredits = 0;
string courseName;
double gradePoints = 0, overallGPA = 0;
char target = 'Y';

cout << "Welcome to GPA Calculator!" << endl;

    //input data
    cout << "Enter number of courses: \t";
    cin >> numbCourses;
    cout << "Enter course name: \t";
    cin >> courseName;
    cout << "Enter the Credit Hours: \t";
    cin >> creditHours;
    cout << "Enter Grade Earned (as A = 4 | B = 3 | C = 2 | D = 1): \t";
    cin >> grade;
    cout << endl;

    
//calculations for GPA | Sum of grades for all classes / Total number of classes you’ve taken

    gradePoints = grade * creditHours;
    totalCredits = creditHours =+ creditHours;
    overallGPA = grade / numbCourses;

//output
  cout << "Course name: " << courseName << '\n';
  cout << "Number of credit hours: " << creditHours << '\n';
  cout << "Grade: " << grade << '\n';
  cout << "Grade Points: " << gradePoints << '\n';
  cout << "total credits: " << totalCredits << '\n';
  cout << "Overall GPA: " << overallGPA << '\n';
  cout << endl;

        

//display if student is on Dean's list
 if (overallGPA >= 3.0)
 {
    cout << "You have made the Dean's list!" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
    cout << "Time to improve your grades!" << endl;
 }

//target GPA
double currentGPA = 0, targetGPA = 0, cCredit = 0, aCredit = 0;
    cout << "*___________________________________________________*" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to use the Target GPA Calculator?\t";
    cin >> target;

    if (target == 'N' | target == 'n')
    {
        return 0;
    }


    //input data
    cout << "Enter your current GPA: \t";
    cin >> currentGPA;
    cout << "Enter your target GPA: \t";
    cin >> targetGPA;
    cout << "Enter your current number of credits: \t";
    cin >> cCredit;
    cout << "Enter additional credits: \t";
    cin >> aCredit;

    //calculations for target GPA

    // I have yet to enter this section


return 0;
```

}

Comment: You've a typo: `if (target == 'N' | target == 'n')` – did you mean `||`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all of the stuff after obtaining the `numbCourses` value in this.

```
for (int course = 0; course < numbCourses; ++course)
{
...
}
```

Please note that `=+` should be `+=`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main() {


//Needed variables

int numbCourses = 0, creditHours = 0, grade = 0, totalCredits = 0;
string courseName;
double gradePoints = 0, overallGPA = 0;
char target = 'Y';

cout << "Welcome to GPA Calculator!" << endl;

    //input data
for(int i=0;i<numbCourses;i++)         //<- I added a for loop here to loop through all 
                                       //course


    {cout << "Enter number of courses: \t";
    cin >> numbCourses;
    cout << "Enter course name: \t";
    cin >> courseName;
    cout << "Enter the Credit Hours: \t";
    cin >> creditHours;
    cout << "Enter Grade Earned (as A = 4 | B = 3 | C = 2 | D = 1): \t";
    cin >> grade;
    cout << endl;
    }
    
//calculations for GPA | Sum of grades for all classes / Total number of classes you’ve taken

    gradePoints = grade * creditHours;
    totalCredits = creditHours =+ creditHours;
    overallGPA = grade / numbCourses;

//output
  cout << "Course name: " << courseName << '\n';
  cout << "Number of credit hours: " << creditHours << '\n';
  cout << "Grade: " << grade << '\n';
  cout << "Grade Points: " << gradePoints << '\n';
  cout << "total credits: " << totalCredits << '\n';
  cout << "Overall GPA: " << overallGPA << '\n';
  cout << endl;

        

//display if student is on Dean's list
 if (overallGPA >= 3.0)
 {
    cout << "You have made the Dean's list!" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
    cout << "Time to improve your grades!" << endl;
 }

//target GPA
double currentGPA = 0, targetGPA = 0, cCredit = 0, aCredit = 0;
    cout << "*___________________________________________________*" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to use the Target GPA Calculator?\t";
    cin >> target;

    if (target == 'N' | target == 'n')
    {
        return 0;
    }


    //input data
    cout << "Enter your current GPA: \t";
    cin >> currentGPA;
    cout << "Enter your target GPA: \t";
    cin >> targetGPA;
    cout << "Enter your current number of credits: \t";
    cin >> cCredit;
    cout << "Enter additional credits: \t";
    cin >> aCredit;

    //calculations for target GPA

    // I have yet to enter this section


return 0;
}
```